# Can you make navigation.goBack from goBack to some routes?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Let say I got 4 pages,

```
A, B, C, D
```

let say A,B routes will accessible all the time, But D route will have limited access.

```
A
  -> C <- D
B
```

I got a `navigation.goBack()` button on `page C`. What I want to do is If I go from

When I go from `A to C` Pressing go back will bring me back to A,

When I go from `B to C` Pressing go back will bring me back to B,

But when I come from `D to C` Pressing go back, I don't want the component to going back to D. But I will navigate user back to A component

How Can I modify the React navigation `goBack` Action.

I already tried using

```
props.navigation.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{name: 'C'}],
})
```

on Component D and go back to C, But the goBack button stop working in Component C

Comment: Put a redirect on page D?

Comment: @acetheninja You mean direct the user back to `A` rather than `C`. It won't work Because Its kind of the checkout process.  The user will need to go back to C after certain button is clicked

Comment: It depends on your use case but what I'm suggesting is that whenever certain conditions are met, going back will take the user to C otherwise it will take them to A.

Answer (score 0):

Not `navigation.goBack()` but you may use `navigation.navigate("the file name")`
This will work, but i dont think navigation.goBack() can work, cause goBack() will only make you go to where you come from.